# Simple stack struct program in C returns "(null)" instead of peek() value

Tags: c, struct

I'm pretty new to C and I wanted to write a simple stack program to train myself a little bit, and I thought it was going to be simple but I ran into a lot of problems...
When I run it from the command line in Windows, all it writes on the screen is `(null)`, when what I want it to display is the value in `a.list[0]` which should be equal to `123`.
Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct stack {
    int list[256];
    int lastelement;
};

void push(struct stack stack, int newelement) {
    stack.list[stack.lastelement] = newelement;
    stack.lastelement++;
};

int peek(struct stack stack) {
    return stack.list[stack.lastelement];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    struct stack a = {0, 0};

    push(a, 123);

    int result = peek(a);

    printf("%s\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void push(struct stack stack` *copies* the stack - any modifications inside that function are local

Comment: Also `printf("%s\n", result);` is wrong, the specifier for printing an `int` is `%d`

Comment: Oh ok, so I need to pass a pointer right?

Comment: The `lastElement` indexes one beyond the last element that is in use.  You are peeking at the wrong spot.

Comment: Debugger...........!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass structure as value on the stack any changes will not propagate.
Also you accessing past the initialized element in your list. Print decimal value as `"%d"`, `"%s"` is for strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct stack {
    int list[256];
    int lastelement;
};

void push(struct stack *stack, int newelement) {

    stack->list[stack->lastelement] = newelement;
    stack->lastelement++;
};

int peek(struct stack *stack) {
    return stack->list[(stack->lastelement)-1];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    struct stack a = {0, 0};

    push(&a, 123);
    push(&a, 456);

    int result = peek(&a);

    printf("%d\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
456
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it solved my problem, and even though I feel stupid now, I would like to point out that in `(stack->lastelement)-1`, the -1 is not needed if you just invert the position of `stack->list[stack->lastelement] = newelement;` and `stack->lastelement++;`